# How to switch on CORS for IBM Code Engine Application

Tags: cors, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have created a Code Engine application which is exposing a couple of APIs. Its container is built using a Cloud Native Buildpack, so I can pick up fixes to security issues.

I can successfully invoke the APIs from a browser and from curl, but when I attempt to invoke the APIs from a React.js app, I get the following error -

```
Access to fetch at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I need to enable cors on my code-engine application, but am struggling to determine how.

The react.js app skeleton was created by running `npx create-react-app`. I am testing the react.js app locally running `npm start`. When it is ready it will be built by running `npm run build`.

The REST call to the Code Engine Application API is in a fire one time `useEffect`, where `endpoint` and `method` are inputs to the component:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!endpoint || !method) return;
        console.log('Starting');

        const appurl = `https://${endpoint}${method}`;

        fetch(appurl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            }
        })
        //.then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(console.error);

        console.log('url is ', appurl);
    },[]);
```

Comment: Could you add some more details? The CE app is deployed and works, right? Where is the React.js app hosted, how does a request look like? From where is the error with "http://localhost:3000"? Why localhost?

Comment: localhost as that is where I am developing and testing the react.js app. I'll add some more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For POST CORS requests, your app has to serve the OPTIONS preflight request. Maybe that’s the issue? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS or other resources on CORS. For POST requests in particular, you need to provide Access-Control-Allow-Headers options.

Because the Code Engine app with the API is powered by Node.js / Express, and all that needs to be done is to add `cors` as a dependency, then add

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html